# How to prevent locking and possible performance issue

Tags: mysql, performance, performance-tuning

I'm working on a website that lets users and admins to generate reports, and those reports require many database queries - they can take over one minute to complete. I noticed when these reports are being generated, the website might freeze for all its users.

These reports consist basically of SELECT queries, i.e., they don't update or insert anything into the MySQL database.

How do you guys implement intensive database operations such as report generations in production environments?

Comment: What is your version? Innodb or MyISAM? Can you show some typical SELECT queries? Nobody can understand your environment and your problem.

Comment: What is the specific concern? That the database can only process one query at a time, that the web site can only support one user at a time, that a user can only process one report at a time, or ... ? Closing as "too broad" in the meantime.

Answer (score 1):

- Don't use MyISAM; use InnoDB.  (to avoid "table locks")
- Build and maintain Summary tables.  (often 10x faster)
- Let's see the slow queries; maybe they can be improved.